# Loop through multiple columns using SQL CASE to populate another columns (transformation)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing a transform for data migration and need some help with the following logic as I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Apologies if it's duplicate and thanks in advance for the replies.

**Source columns:** source1, source2, source3, source4
(not all the columns contain data)

**Order to follow (source):** source1, source2, source3, source4

**Target columns:** col1,col1,col3,col4

**Business Logic:**

1. Populate col1 with non null value from source columns
2. Populate col2 with NEXT non null value from source columns, provided col1 is not null
3. Col3 & col4 follows the same logic.

**Required:** SQL CASE statement

**Source Example:**

| ID | source1 | source2 | source3 | source4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  | val1.3 |  |
| 2 | val2.1 | val2.2 |  |  |
| 3 | val3.1 | val3.2 | val3.3 | val3.4 |
| 4 |  | val4.2 | val4.3 | val4.4 |
| 5 |  |  | val5.3 | val5.4 |
| 6 | val6.1 |  | val6.3 |  |
| 7 |  | val7.2 |  | val7.4 |
| 8 | val8.1 | val8.2 |  | val8.4 |
| 9 | val9.1 |  | val9.3 | val9.4 |
| 10 | val10.1 | val10.2 | val10.3 |  |

**Expected Target columns:**

| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val1.3 |  |  |  |
| 2 | val2.1 | val2.2 |  |  |
| 3 | val3.1 | val3.2 | val3.3 | val3.4 |
| 4 | val4.2 | val4.3 | val4.4 |  |
| 5 | val5.3 | val5.4 |  |  |
| 6 | val6.1 | val6.3 |  |  |
| 7 | val7.2 | val7.4 |  |  |
| 8 | val8.1 | val8.2 | val8.4 |  |
| 9 | val9.1 | val9.3 | val9.4 |  |
| 10 | val10.1 | val10.2 | val10.3 |  |

Hope my query is clear and again thank you very much for your help.

Expecting:

| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val1.3 |  |  |  |
| 2 | val2.1 | val2.2 |  |  |
| 3 | val3.1 | val3.2 | val3.3 | val3.4 |
| 4 | val4.2 | val4.3 | val4.4 |  |
| 5 | val5.3 | val5.4 |  |  |
| 6 | val6.1 | val6.3 |  |  |
| 7 | val7.2 | val7.4 |  |  |
| 8 | val8.1 | val8.2 | val8.4 |  |
| 9 | val9.1 | val9.3 | val9.4 |  |
| 10 | val10.1 | val10.2 | val10.3 |  |

Comment: Take a look at COALESCE function together with a CASE you should be able to do it I think

Answer (score 4):

While a `CASE` expression could potentially be used, the conditions get progressively more complicated as each column selector has to enumerate the various null/not-null combinations of the source columns to determine which value to select.

Instead, if you combine (unpivot) your source values into a single column and assign source numbers, you can exclude the null values and then use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to assign target column numbers. Then it is a matter of pivoting the resulting data back into a multi-column form.

The SQL `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` syntax can be used to do this, but I prefer using `CROSS APPLY (VALUES ...)` and *conditional aggregation* to accomplish the same.

```
SELECT
    S.ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN VR.RowNum = 1 THEN VR.SourceValue END) AS col1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN VR.RowNum = 2 THEN VR.SourceValue END) AS col2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN VR.RowNum = 3 THEN VR.SourceValue END) AS col3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN VR.RowNum = 4 THEN VR.SourceValue END) AS col4
FROM Source S
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT VS.SourceValue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY VS.SourceNum) AS RowNum
    FROM (
       VALUES
           (1, S.source1),
           (2, S.source2),
           (3, S.source3),
           (4, S.source4)
    ) VS(SourceNum, SourceValue)
    WHERE SourceValue IS NOT NULL
) VR
GROUP BY S.ID
ORDER BY S.ID
```

Results (with an additional all-null case):

| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val1.3 | null | null | null |
| 2 | val2.1 | val2.2 | null | null |
| 3 | val3.1 | val3.2 | val3.3 | val3.4 |
| 4 | val4.2 | val4.3 | val4.4 | null |
| 5 | val5.3 | val5.4 | null | null |
| 6 | val6.1 | val6.3 | null | null |
| 7 | val7.2 | val7.4 | null | null |
| 8 | val8.1 | val8.2 | val8.4 | null |
| 9 | val9.1 | val9.3 | val9.4 | null |
| 10 | val10.1 | val10.2 | val10.3 | null |
| 11 | null | null | null | null |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ikGayAV8) for a working example.

Since the results are text columns, you can also add `ISNULL(..., '')` to the final select expressions to replace null values with empty strings. See [this modified demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fPWUlEl5).

Comment: Thank you very much for the logic. I tried using this logic on Snowflake where I'm doing the transforms but it failed since OUTER APPLY is not applicable there. I then changed OUTER APPLY to LEFT OUTER JOIN but then it failed on the S.source1 stating that its not recognized.

Comment: Well, Snowflake isn't SQL Server. You tagged SQL Server in your question, so that is the audience who saw it and that is the answer that I offered. Unfortunately, I do not know Snowflake and a quick look at the documentation shows that is has many differences. Snowflake does support PIVOT and UNPIVOT, so you might be able to read up and use those capabilities. I also saw a post stating that LATERAL or LEFT LATERAL joins may be Snowflake equivalents to SQL Server's CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY. I suggest you update your post with the correct tags. Someone else may come along who can help.